# Parser: The statement dialect could not be resolved due to ambiguity

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I use `SSAS` and `Sql Server 2008 R2` .

I write this query :

```
Select
[Product].[Product Categories],[Product].[Category]
on columns
From [Adventure Works]
```

And I get this error :

```
Executing the query ...
Parser: The statement dialect could not be resolved due to ambiguity.
Execution complete
```

And then I use {} like this query :

```
Select
{[Product].[Product Categories],[Product].[Category]}
on columns
From [Adventure Works]
```

And i get this error :

```
Executing the query ...
Query (2, 2) Two sets specified in the  function have different dimensionality.
Execution complete
```

Then i use this query :

```
Select
([Product].[Product Categories],[Product].[Category])
on columns
From [Adventure Works]
```

And i get this result :

[image]

I want get sum default measure for all product categories members

and one columns that have total sum.

But i need a result that have side by side columns ?

How i can get this result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what measure you are using or whether you are just trying to get the all value for each of those dimension attributes or if you want each possible attribute for the two. It looks like you either didn't list the measure in your question or you are using the default measure. Just put the measure in your columns of the queries below if you have one. You were getting the error about dimensionality because you were asking it for two different dimension hierarchies. Although the values might be the same, those are two distinct hierarchies. You just need a crossjoin and then it should work.

If you are trying to get the result you listed at the top, just side by side, try:

```
Select {Measures.DefaultMember} on columns,
```

{{[Product].[Product Category Name].[All]} * {[Product].[Category].[all]}} on rows
    from [Adventure Works]

If you are actually wanting the list of product categories side by side you can do:

```
Select {Measures.DefaultMember} on columns, 
{[Product].[Product Categories].[All].children * [Product].[Category].children} on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: first your query have this error : Executing the query ...
Query (2, 1) The  function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

Execution complete

Comment: and in your second query you forget query default measure.and result of your query have only two rows without any columns.

Comment: @loup yeah, i noted that in my question because i wasn't sure if you actually meant to select the default member.  I have updated it to include the default member in the query.

Comment: @loup, sorry i forgot to add extra brackets in my first query.  It's just a funny thing about how MDX works.  Here's a good article about why you need the brackets when using the * crossjoin notation: http://www.softwaremasons.com/MartinsBlog/tabid/74/EntryId/56/Is-SSAS-Too-Lenient-on-MDX-Syntax.aspx